# Vue.js remove always last item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, splice, vuejs2

I'm trying to have a simple filter where when I click on button "add filter" I will duplicate filter and it will add to array with filters. There is no problem to add but then I cannot remove (cross icon) the right input - I always remove the last item from array instead the right one. I have this code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="pref-search">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default filter-col btn-sm" v-on:click="addFilter">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add filter
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-for="filter in extFilters.filters" style="margin: 10px 0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="pref-search">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default filter-col btn-sm" v-on:click="addFilter">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add filter
        </button>
        <span v-on:click="removeFilter(filter)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is Vue.js:

```
var data = {
  'filters': [],
}

// app Vue instance
var app = new Vue({
  // app initial state
  data: {
    extFilters: data,
  },

  // methods that implement data logic.
  methods: {
    addFilter: function() {
      this.extFilters.filters.push({
        andor: 'a',
        search_in: '',
        operator: '',
        text: ''
      })
    },

    removeFilter: function(filter) {
      var index = this.extFilters.filters.indexOf(filter);
      this.extFilters.filters.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
})

// mount
app.$mount('.jumbotron')
```

Problem is when I add for example three filters and I would like to remove first filter then it will remove always the last one. Why it is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my problem on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmz9kwoa/1/). Best answer would be also in jsFiddle.

Comment: because you using var index = this.extFilters.filters.indexOf(filter); , always return first filtter from the list. change the indexOf() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is... https://jsfiddle.net/mariaczi/hed0ew5o/1/

You did not add `v-model='filter.text'` to the text input which makes all your filters looking the same, that's why it was not working.

Working properly now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Might be worth updating the fiddle to reflect that the original `removeFilter `function worked as implemented and the missing binding was the only issue.